# Sublist starting with a certain object

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and I want to iterate through the sublist starting with the object that meets a certain criterion.

(Concretely, the list of declared fields for a class, starting with field such-and-such, known by name not by integer index.)

Obviously one solution would be to iterate through the entire list, setting a flag when the particular object has been found, but it occurs to me to wonder whether Java 8 with its improved support for higher-order programming, provides a more elegant way to do it.

What's the most elegant/idiomatic way to do this in Java 8? (Performance isn't a consideration; the code in question will only be run once per program execution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the `indexOf` method to act like as a predicate, where you can give a custom property to tell whether you find the first object that satisfies it.

It can be done using an helper method.

```
static <T> List<T> getSubList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> pred){
    return list.subList(list.indexOf(list.stream().filter(pred).findFirst().get()), list.size());
}
```

What it does is:

- get a [`Stream<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from the list
- apply a filter to it
- find the first element that satisfied the given predicate
- get the object in the resulting [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) calling `get()`
- use `indexOf` on the list to get the index of this object
- return a `sublist` of the original list

Then you can call it like;

```
List<MyClass> subList = getSubList(list, o -> o.b.startsWith("10"));
```

For a small example, here's how you can take a sublist from the first object where its String value starts with a 10 until the end of the list.

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            list.add(new MyClass(i, String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(getSubList(list, o -> o.s.startsWith("10"))); //[MyClass [a=10, b=10], MyClass [a=11, b=11], MyClass [a=12, b=12], MyClass [a=13, b=13], MyClass [a=14, b=14]]

    }
    static <T> List<T> getSubList(List<T> list, Predicate<T> pred){
        return list.subList(list.indexOf(list.stream().filter(pred).findFirst().get()), list.size());
    }
}
class MyClass {
    int i;
    String s;
    public MyClass(int i,String s){
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [i=" + i + ", s=" + s + "]";
    }

}
```

You can add more checks, for example to see if you have a value from the `Optional` (using `isPresent()`) you get by calling `findFirst`, but you have the main idea of how to do it.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

With [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html), you can do

```
// list is an instance of List<T> from which the sublist is wanted
Iterable<T> sublist = Iterables.skip(list, list.indexOf(certainObject));
```

However, this does not use any new features of Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
List<T> list = ...;
Optional<T> first = list.stream()
            .filter(f -> f.name.equals("field name"))
            .findFirst();
return first.isPresent()
            ? list.subList(list.indexOf(first))
            : Collections.emptyList();
```

ps: on mobile so not sure it compiles but the general idea should work.